# Cordova Android - getCurrentPosition does not fire error callback when Location Services are disabled

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, geolocation

I am working on a building an Android app with Cordova. I am using the browser's `navigator.geolocation` api and it has been pretty solid. However on certain phones when Location Service are turned off in the device settings the `getCurrentPosition()` function never returns a success or error callback.

I am passing a timeout option of 5000, but is there any way to ensure that the error callback is fired when the Location Settings are turned off in the device?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. If I find anything, I'll let you know!

Comment: I think the best option here is to just use the timeout as you said, and assume that getting a timeout could mean location is off. I'm making an error message that says to check if location is on. Not ideal, so hopefully someone fixes this!

Comment: issue still exists, any soln. yet?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a parameter "timeout". If a GPS in state "OFF" the event will be fire on the timeout of the coonnection to GPS.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError,{timeout: 5000});
```

Enjoy!